# Protocol buffer in Python: How to set value to the nested element

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

i'm having problem while trying to set the value of the nested element in Protobuf file with Python. I have the following protobuf:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;

message OuterLayer{
    InnerLayer sim_card_data = 1;
    string version_number = 3;

    message InnerLayer{
        string iccid = 1;
        string imei = 2;
    }
```

In Python, i set the value by using:

```
raw = OuterLayer()
raw.version_number = "1.0"
raw.InnerLayer.iccid="1"
raw.InnerLayer.imei="2"
```

By printing the raw class print(raw) i got only:

```
version_number: "1"
```

The values of the Innerlayer seems not to be set. What am I doing wrong ? Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InnerLayer` is the class name not the parameter name so doing the following should work

```
raw = OuterLayer()
raw.version_number = "1.0"
raw.sim_card_data = InnerLayer()
raw.sim_card_data.iccid = "1"
raw.sim_card_data.imei = "2"
```